# How to split column values and add to a temp table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a table `tblInstitution` as follows

```
InstitutionCode   InstitutionDesc
---------------------------------
ABC               Abra Cada Brad   
DEF               Def Fede Eeee 
GHJ               Gee Hee
```

I want to split the values in `InstitutionDesc` and store it based on the institution code

```
InstitutionCode   Token   Score
-------------------------------
ABC               Abra      0
ABC               Cada      0
ABC               Brad      0
DEF               Def       0
DEF               Fede      0
DEF               Eeee      0
GHJ               Gee       0
GHJ               Hee       0
```

Is there a way I can do this in a set-based operation?

I have seen examples where a single column value can be split into multiple column values of the same row. But I am not able to find an example where the same column can be split into different rows. I am not sure what exactly should be searched for. Is it something to do with CTEs.

Comment: There is a good chance that the answer to your question is here:  http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive CTE option...

```
If      Object_ID('tempdb..#tblInstitution') Is Not Null Drop Table #tblInstitution;
Create  Table #tblInstitution (InstitutionCode Varchar(10), InstitutionDesc Varchar(50));

Insert  #tblInstitution (InstitutionCode, InstitutionDesc)
Values  ('ABC','Abra Cada Brad'),
        ('DEF','Def Fede Eeee'),
        ('GHJ','Gee Hee'),
        ('KLM','Kappa');

With    base As
(
        Select  InstitutionCode, 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(InstitutionDesc)) As InstitutionDesc
        From    #tblInstitution
),      recur As
(
        Select  InstitutionCode,
                Left(InstitutionDesc, CharIndex(' ', InstitutionDesc + ' ') - 1) As Token,
                Case
                When    CharIndex(' ', InstitutionDesc) > 0
                Then    Right(InstitutionDesc, Len(InstitutionDesc) - CharIndex(' ', InstitutionDesc))
                Else    Null
                End     As Remaining
        From    base
        Union   All
        Select  InstitutionCode,
                Left(Remaining, CharIndex(' ', Remaining + ' ') - 1) As Token,
                Case
                When    CharIndex(' ', Remaining) > 0
                Then    Right(Remaining, Len(Remaining) - CharIndex(' ', Remaining))
                Else    Null
                End     As Remaining
        From    recur
        Where   Remaining Is Not Null
)
Select  InstitutionCode,
        Token,
        0   As Score
From    recur
Order   By InstitutionCode
```

Comment: Whoa!! Thats some really neat code.. I would never have got it. An additional doubt here. If I have a table-valued function which can split the string delimited by space, is it going to help in making the code modularized? Or will it affect the performance? Function output would be something like this:  Select * from fnSplitString("abc cde def"," "); Output would be  **Items**  ------  abc  
cde  
def

[How do i get a new line, 2 spaces are not working for me. :( I meant the output to be of 3 rows]